Add a LUT to display pseudocolors in tif images
I want to create images with multiple pseudocolor channels.
This means that the pixel values represent a color from a designated lookup table (LUT).
library(RBioFormats)

img = read.image(mockFile(sizeX = 200,
                          sizeY = 200,
                          sizeZ = 1,
                          sizeC = 4,
                          pixelType = "uint8",
                          bitsPerPixel = 8)
                 normalize = FALSE)
set.seed(666)
img[,,] = round(runif(200*200*4, min = 0, max = 255))

This will create an image of size 200x200 pixels with four channels and random pixel values.
For example, I would like the pixel values of the first to fourth channel to represent 'green', 'red', 'blue' and 'gray', respectively.
In other words, I would expect the lookup tables to look something like that:
Channel1:
0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0
2 0 2 0 
3 0 3 0
4 0 4 0
...

Channel4:
0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 
4 4 4 4 
... 

where the first column represents the pixel value and the following three columns represent the values for R, G and B.
I have noticed additional parameters in the mockFile() function such as indexed, falseColor and lutLength. Unfortunately, I haven't found a clue HOW to add the LUTs.
Help is much appreciated!
Note: unfortunately I don't have an example image which already contains a LUT. To illustrate more clearly what I want to achieve, see the following image:

Imagine that this image is NOT an RGB image but contains two channels, as well as two LUTs, one for the colour 'green' and one for the color 'gray'.
